# Should I create C++ templated objects from variable with switch statement?

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement

I need to create a number of objects of a templated class. In the final application, the template parameter will be an integer variable. Since variables can't be used as a template parameter, I've created a `switch` statement to create the object.

The problem with this is that the instantiated object isn't available outside the scope of the `switch` statement. In the example I've included below, I've gotten around this by including `section.tell()` multiple times. I'd rather have one statement instead of one for every `case` statement as I've shown as well.

Quetions:

1. How can I use the variable outside the scope of the `switch` statement?
2. Is this the best way to approach this problem?

```c
#include <iostream>

template < int MF >
class Section {
    public:
        void tell(){std::cout << "\tI am MF = " << MF << ".\n";}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    std::cout << "\nCreating Sections based on an iterative." << std::endl;
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++){
        std::cout << "i = " << i;

        switch(i){
            case 1:{
                Section<1> section;
                // Make Section tell us who it is
                section.tell();
                break;
           }
            case 2:{
                Section<2> section;
                // Make Section tell us who it is
                section.tell();
                break;
           }
            default:
                std::cout << "\tI don't know how to do this." << std::endl;
        }
        // section.tell();          // Wish I could do this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well this probably won't work. You can't use `i` because the value isn't known at compile-time, so the values will be hard-coded anyway (as shown in the switch statement.)

Comment: That's what I want to know. Can I use the `Section` variables later? What C++ magic do I need to do to use them later? The rudimentary example I give compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: It compiles fine, sure, because the values are hardcoded (and therefore known at compile time.) If you wanted to use `i` as the template parameter, it won't work because `i` is determined at runtime. In other words, there's no way to put `Section` outside the scope of the switch statement and do what you want. Instead, just put `section.tell()` inside each case statement (if they are only trivial cases, does it really matter if you're repeating yourself?)

Comment: A terrible hack involving a non-templated base class for the template class comes to mind. But before I post such an abomination as an answer, please tell us why you think you'd need this.

Comment: @larsmans I'm trying to avoid creating a `Section` class and then `Section1`, `Section2`, etc. classes which inherit from `Section`, each with customized methods. I'm reading some text files and creating some C++ objects based on the data in the files. The structure I created above seemed to come naturally from the structure of the files. Happy to entertain other suggestions.

Comment: If you want to create objects, then create objects. Now you're creating *types*. How different are the behaviors of the various sections?

Comment: The different sections can be very different---at least as far as what is contained. The access and format of the text is still the same.

Comment: What matters is how the behavior of the objects changes. If you can reasonably subsume their different behaviors in a single class, then that's the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is somehow close to the [class factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

What you can possibly do is

1. define an interface (abstract class) `ISection` which serves as base class to your `Section<T>` template classes.

   ```
   class ISection{
       public:
          virtual void tell() = 0;
          virtual ~ISection(){};
    };

   template <int i>
   class Section : public ISection {
          public:
             /* tell() is overridden and (in this setting) it is parametrized by i */ 
             void tell(){ 
                /*some thing, e.g.*/
                std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl; 
             } 
    };
   ```
2. bind your `Section<T>` instances (whichever of them, depending on the template parameter) via `ISection` (smart) pointers, e.g.

   ```
     std::shared_ptr<ISection> myInstance( new Section<1>() ) ;
   ```

Hence, in the `switch` framework, you would have something like

```
std::shared_ptr<ISection> myInstance;

switch (i):
     case 1:
          myInstance = std::shared_ptr<ISection>(new Section<1>());
          break;
     case 2:
          myInstance = std::shared_ptr<ISection>(new Section<2>());
          break;
```

and so on.

Finally, you can invoke the method `tell()` via

```
    myInstance->tell();
```

.

Regarding your second question, I would say that, unless your template parameters are actual types (i.e. not static `int` values), I would not use such template machinery.

Rather, I would simply pass the `int` parameter to the constructor of a non-template class, i.e.

```
   Section mySection(i);
```

.

Of course, on the other hand, you might want to play some dark meta-programming trick on `i`.

Comment: You'll need a virtual destructor on `ISection` too.

Comment: I like this idea. It makes me wonder if a template is right implementation for this problem.